# Solving an equation with rational function under square root

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to solve for D in the equation below and keep coming up with different answers. I can hopefully take it from there.

$$A=B\sqrt{1-\frac{2C(\frac{D}{E^2})}{FG^2}}$$

Thank you

Comment: It would be helpful to show the steps you took in each case so that we can help spot where you may have made a mistake.

Comment: You could get the correct answer from Wolfram Alpha, to compare it to yours.

Answer (score 2):

simplest solution i think:
$$
A=B\cdot \sqrt{1−{2CD\over FG^2E^2}} \iff A^2=B^2\Big(1−{2CD\over FG^2E^2}\Big) \iff \\
\iff A^2=B^2\Big(1−{2CD\over FG^2E^2}\Big) \iff \Big({A\over B}\Big)^2=\Big(1−{2CD\over FG^2E^2}\Big) \iff\\ 
\iff 1-(A/B)^2={2CD\over FG^2E^2} \iff (1-(A/B)^2) (FG^2E^2)=2CD \iff\\
\iff D={F\over 2C}(GE)^2(1-\Big({A \over B}\Big)^2)  
$$

Answer (score 0):

$A=B\sqrt{1-\frac{2C*(\frac{D}{E^2})}{FG^2}}$

$D = \cfrac{B^2E^2FG^2-A^2E^2FG^2}{2B^2 C}$

Can you work backwards more easily? I would likely find it far easier to work back from here.

Comment: @Graydad, I don't have the rep to comment on you, but your first step put $1-$ in the brackets, when it is outside of them.

Comment: Oops! I got lost in OP's parentheses. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @graydad That's alright, Latex definitely would have helped him